# Photo browser with previous and next button , how?

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

I want to make a gallery with previous and next button in my iPhone app.

If anyone has idea , link , exampler or something that lead me to implement the gallery  please provide me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thee20 framework](http://github.com/facebook/three20), they have a [great gallery example](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3447/3378092101_b064d8e339_o.jpg)

Comment: I have seen it but I can't understand how to include that lib in my proj and how to use that gallery class .If you know how to use it , Can you explain me , if you don;t mind .

Comment: there is a very clear tutorial on the front page of the project. it takes 9 steps to include.

Comment: I have completed all steps but still it gives on the header file <Three20/Three20.> what is wrong can you tell ?

Comment: It's; #import <Three20/Three20.h>

Answer (score 5):

I've written a simple and easy to use photo browser called MWPhotoBrowser. I decided to create it as Three20, while very good, was too heavy/bloated as all I needed was a photo viewer.

It is an implementation of a photo viewer that I wrote allowing the user to view one or more images in a similar way to the native Photos app. It can display one or more images by providing either UIImage objects, file paths to images on the device, or URLs images online. Photos can also be zoomed, panned, and navigated with previous/next buttons.

[View MWPhotoBrowser on GitHub](http://bit.ly/mwphotobrowser)

Hope this helps!